# pandas.DataFrame.from_records changes column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I type this line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor("file1", ['colA','colB'])
#this line reads a file with the specified columns.
```

The result renames the first column as 0 and the other as 1.

If you see in the documentation. There is an extra `columns` parameter.

> Column names to use. If the passed data do not have names associated
>   with them, this argument provides names for the columns. Otherwise
>   this argument indicates the order of the columns in the result.

The problem is that the whole code is in a loop and specifying this column is not possible because in each loop different columns are being read. How can I keep the initial columns without turning them to 0 and 1.

**UPDATE**

```
dict1 = {'file_name_1': ['on_column', 'another_column'], 'file_name_2': ['again_column']}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v))
    df['count_of_a_column']=[df['colA'].value_counts().loc[x] for x in df['colA']]

#When the df is made the column names are already ruined. 
#They are called 0 and 1 if they are two. Thus the last line of code won't 
#find the columns that imported.
```

Comment: `in each loop different columns are being read`. So you can define in advance a list with the appropriate columns for each `for` loop iteration? If so, you can specify it; if not, Python won't guess.

Comment: @user51332,  that will help indeed a lot for SO fellows here to understand

Comment: Updated the question.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column labels may be modified. Just name your columns explicitly after you've created your dataframe:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v))
    df.columns = v
    df['count_of_a_column']=[df['colA'].value_counts().loc[x] for x in df['colA']]
```

Comment: `in every loop different column names are needed`. Yes, so in each loop `v` is different. What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry.I didn't notice that.Great answer.Thanks